# Primefaces menuitem change custom icon

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menuitem

I have some problems to customize the icon of menuitem component.

I tried this form but i don't have success:

```
<p:menuitem value="Clientes" outcome="/clientes/CadastroCliente" icon="resources/images/person.png"/>
```

I too try use css

```
<p:menuitem value="Clientes" outcome="/clientes/CadastroCliente" icon="user"/>

.user{
    background: url('resources/images/menu/users.png') no-repeat;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```

I use PrimeFaces 5.

Comment: Your second way is correct. But I am afraid the path to the image is incorrect. This one you used is relative to the folder where the class is. make sure you put the correct path to this image.

Comment: If you look in your javascript console, you'll see any errors (probably an HTTP-404) related to retrieving the icon image

Comment: Please, see this image to check if my path is correct http://i.snag.gy/Uv2zi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p:menuitem value="Clientes" outcome="/clientes/CadastroCliente" icon="user"/>

.user {
    background: url(../images/menu/users.png) !important;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}
```

You need `!important` to overwrite the default image of Primefaces and create the folder `images` directly under src directory

Answer (score 0):

primeFaces 6

If you don’t want to create your own skin and setup the style directly and show a icon/image only,

You can do this: 
Note, there is no *value*=”avoid” attribute inside the  tag.

```
<p:menuitem url="./config.xhtml" styleClass="myStyleName"/>
```

The result is:

```
<li role="menuitem">
    <a tabindex="-1" 
          class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all myStyleName" 
           href="./Konfiguration.xhtml">
            <span class="ui-menuitem-text"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Note there will be a empty traffic blow up span tag.

used style:

```
a.ui-menuitem-link.ui-corner-all.myStyleName{
    background: url("img/zahnrad.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 1em; 
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Important is the **background-size** in my case 1em

If you would like to add a icon with text so do this:

```
<p:menuitem url="./Konfiguration.xhtml" 
    styleClass="myStyleName" value="navigation" />
```

The result is:

```
<li role="menuitem">
    <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all myStyleName" href="./config.xhtml">
        <span class="ui-menuitem-text">navigation</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

used style:

```
a.ui-menuitem-link.ui-corner-all.myStyleName{
    background: url("img/zahnrad.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 1em;
    padding-left: 1.2em; /* reserved text space */
    /*
    right to left
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 1.2em;
    */
}
```

Comment: "Note there will be a empty traffic blow up span tag." - could you elaborate?